# MF bit in IP datagram

Tags: tcp

I'm learning TCP/IP suite,
and when I encounter the MF bit which is set to zero on the last fragment, 
I want to know what happen if the fragments of the datagram are received out of order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing, seeing an MF bit on a fragmented packet simply says it is the last packet *sent* with the biggest offset, not that it is the last packet to wait for.